# postgresql - is there an alternative to datename() function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am finding alternatives to various functions of SQL Server in PostgreSQL.

Is there an alternative to the following SQL Server code in PostgreSQL?

`SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

Note: The above query returns the "weekday-name" of the current day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the official documentation for date formats
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html

Example usage:

```
SELECT to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Day')
```